# Nginx RTMP stream key

Tags: nginx, stream, rtmp, obs

This is my Nginx RTMP config file

```
worker_processes auto;
rtmp_auto_push on;
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        listen [::]:1935 ipv6only=on;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            push rtmp://fra05.contribute.live-video.net/app/KEY;
        }
    }
}
```

I use OBS studio to push stream
How to check OBS studio stream key in the Nginx file to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
rtmp {
  server {
    listen 1935;
      
    application stream {
      live on;
      on_publish http://yourdomain.com/rtmp_auth.php;
    }
  }
}
```

The rtmp module will send a "form" POST to th url you give it, your streamkey from, for example OBS, will be in the $_POST['name'] variable. you can check it against a file/database with the script then return a 201 (all ok, publishing is granted) or a 404 (not allowed to publish)